# Old user accounts generated on new instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

When I generate a new VM instance, I notice that if I go the the /home directory, I see the home directories of past user accounts I've created.  I find this odd since I'm creating a new instance from scratch.  Can anyone please advise why this might be happening.  I made sure to delete all old instances and disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Compute Engine creates the accounts based on your instance metadata or in your project metadata if you don’t have instance metadata.

In this case it’s using the project’s metadata. To see your project’s metadata go to Compute->Compute Engine->Metadata in the Developers Console and click on ‘SSH keys’ on the top of the page. There, you can find a list with two columns:

- On the left you can see the username that will be generated every time you create an instance.
- On the right you can see the SSH key that will be stored in `<username>/.ssh/authorized_keys` for that user.

There can be more than one SSH key per user. Therefore, if you want to remove all old users from there, you just need to click on ‘Edit’ and remove all the lines where appears those users in the left column.

**Note**:  Be aware that if you remove some users, their home directories will remain in the instances and they won’t be able to SSH into any instance unless they set their SSH keys manually for some specific instances.

**If you want to deepen** and know why everything is working as intended, you can see that the instance is running with runlevel 2 via `sudo runlevel`.

As you may know, once the system boots up, it will execute all the scripts in the `/etc/rc2.d/` folder and there is one responsible of manage all the project accounts for the instance. You can find it at `/etc/rc2.d/S03google-accounts-manager` which is a soft link to `/etc/init.d/google-accounts-manager`.

This one runs `/usr/share/google/google_daemon/manage_accounts.py` which is in a [github repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/tree/master/google-daemon/usr/share/google/google_daemon) as well with the files it uses. This script orchestrates everything related with the accounts using desiredaccounts.py and accountsmanager.py among other.

The [desiredaccounts.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/master/google-daemon/usr/share/google/google_daemon/desired_accounts.py) is used to get all the users and its SSH keys for the instance and project looking at two URLs. You can check the instance metadata with the command:

```
`curl http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/sshKeys?%s -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`
```

And the project metadata with the following command:

```
`curl http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/sshKeys?%s -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`
```

The script will use the project metadata only if the instance metadata it's empty.

Once the script has the desired accounts, it uses [accountsmanager.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/master/google-daemon/usr/share/google/google_daemon/accounts_manager.py#L126) which calls the [UpdateUser method](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/master/google-daemon/usr/share/google/google_daemon/accounts.py#L81)

Finally in [account.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/master/google-daemon/usr/share/google/google_daemon/accounts.py#L81), you can see how it calls the method UserAdd that belongs to utils.py [to create the user](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/master/google-daemon/usr/share/google/google_daemon/utils.py#L69), [add the user to the sudoers file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/master/google-daemon/usr/share/google/google_daemon/accounts.py#L183) and [put the SSH key](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/master/google-daemon/usr/share/google/google_daemon/accounts.py#L250) in his `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Hope it helps.